# How to stop rendering a gameObject that has no rendering component in unity

Tags: unity, rendering, gameobject

[image]
I want to stop rendering this gameObject. But the all-available *renderer.enabled = false* is not working. Is it because it has no rendering component attached? If so, how can I see it when it is not rendered?!

Comment: Can you show us what this object looks like in your game view? Without a renderer, you should see nothing (unless you've enabled gizmos for debugging purposes?), but if it has child objects in the hierarchy with their own renderers then those would be visible. Setting the whole gameObject to inactive will hide its children too, but it will also stop calling update scripts or playing audio, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Oh, yes. It has a child object with _skinned mesh renderer_. Thakn you. I have downloaded from the internet and don't know much about.
Now, could you please tell me how to stop rendering all the parents and children?

Comment: Disable all the renderers. Or, if you also want to stop their scripts/audio, you can set the parent object to inactive as described above (that's the checkbox at the top of the inspector, or `gameObject.SetActive(false)`)

Comment: Thanks. I used the following code. It worked! 
var go : GameObject = gameObject.Find("Armature/Guy");
if(go) go.renderer.enabled = false;

Comment: If that worked for you, feel free to post it as an answer.